# Merge list of dictionaries based on common key

Tags: python, dictionary

How to append a list of dictionaries value to another list.
This my first dict:

```
d=[{'title': 'a', 'num_iid': 36167009077, 'seller_id': 249772349},{'title': 'b', 'num_iid': 1234, 'seller_id': 249772349},{'title': 'c',  'num_iid': 12784, 'seller_id': 12475}]
```

and the list that I want to append it:

```
d1=[{'title': 'a', 'image_url': 'a.jpg', 'subtitle': '140.00', 'buttons': [{'type': 'postback', 'title': 'Details', 'payload': '/'}, {'type': 'postback', 'title': 'shop', 'payload': '/'}]}, {'title': 'b', 'image_url': 'b.jpg', 'subtitle': '2193.00', 'buttons': [{'type': 'postback', 'title': 'Details', 'payload': '/'}, {'type': 'postback', 'title': 'shop', 'payload': '/'}]}, {'title': 'c', 'image_url': 'c.jpg', 'subtitle': '3203.00', 'buttons': [{'type': 'postback', 'title': 'Details', 'payload': '/'}, {'type': 'postback', 'title': 'shop', 'payload': '/'}]}]
```

What I need is insert the 'num_iid' and 'seller_id' in each buttons payload

Expected output:

```
result=[{'title': 'a', 'image_url': 'a.jpg', 'subtitle': '140.00', 'buttons': [{'type': 'postback', 'title': 'Details', 'payload': '36167009077'}, {'type': 'postback', 'title': 'shop ', 'payload': '249772349'}]}, {'title': 'b', 'image_url': 'b.jpg', 'subtitle': '2193.00', 'buttons': [{'type': 'postback', 'title': 'Details', 'payload': '1234'}, {'type': 'postback', 'title': 'shop', 'payload': '249772349'}]}, {'title': 'c', 'image_url': 'c.jpg', 'subtitle': '3203.00', 'buttons': [{'type': 'postback', 'title': 'Details', 'payload': '12784'}, {'type': 'postback', 'title': 'shop', 'payload': '12475'}]}]
```

Answer (score -1):

First:

```py
num_iids = {item['title']: item.get('num_iid', '/') for item in d}
seller_ids = {item['title']: item.get('seller_id', '/') for item in d}
```

Then:

```py
for item in d1:
    title = item['title']
    item['buttons'][0]['payload'] = num_iids.get(title, '/')
    item['buttons'][1]['payload'] = seller_ids.get(title, '/')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for d_find in d:
    for d1_find in d1:
        if d_find['title'] == d1_find['title']:
            d1_find['buttons'][0]['payload'] = d_find['num_iid']
            d1_find['buttons'][1]['payload'] = d_find['seller_id']
            
            break
        
print(d1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with a for loop and `enumerate()`:

```
for i, j in enumerate(d1):
    j['buttons'][0]['payload'] = d[i]['num_iid']
    j['buttons'][1]['payload'] = d[i]['seller_id']
```

Comment: Only if `all(d_item['title'] == d1_item['title'] for d_item, d1_item in zip(d, d1))`

Comment: well that is the case here so...

Comment: it is... but in a real-world case, i would not assume perfect alignment of both lists (nor absence of missing values).

Comment: @nix20536 consider upvoting and accepting if it was useful